# how to convert number into words in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

In one of my crystal report 
my total amount is 158,625.00

I already tried this formula `=( ProperCase( ToWords({?fieldName}, 0)+" only" ))`

it's showing as below:

> one hundred fifty-eight thousand six hundred twenty five only.

but I want it as one lac fifty eight thousand six hundred twenty five only.

Answer (score 0):

The `ToWords()` function's output depends on the language of your PC. From a quick Google, "lac" makes me think you are desiring an output in Indian English as it is a sum generally used when referring to rupees? What is the language setting of your PC currently?

Try changing the language on your PC to Indian English as "lac" is generally an Indian term.

Start > Control Panel > Region and Language > Format: English (Indian)

Comment: What was it set to before you changed it?

Comment: I still think this might be solvable with language settings somewhere. I'm not sure if you can change how your computer defaults putting numbers into words in its current language, but you could look into that.

Otherwise I would say you're next best bet would be to write a formula, which I think would take far more time and effort than it's worth, if even possible.

How vital is this change in diction?

Answer (score -1):

Use following in new formula field.

```
ProperCase( ToWords(yourNumber, 0) )
```

Comment: His issue is the translation to words, he wants it be formatted differently